# Android do special action while shaking

Tags: android, shake

i want do special action while shaking phone 
how can do something while shaking  ?
i want do something until stop shaking by users
how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [what's mentioned here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Gestures-and-Touch-Events#shake-detection). Add [ShakeListener](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/5d1922a5a50fcfb4436a) to your project and add `ShakeListener.Callback` to any Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    implements ShakeListener.Callback {

    @Override
    public void shakingStarted() {
        // Code on started here
    }

    @Override
    public void shakingStopped() {
       // Code on stopped here
    }
}
```

Comment: i want play music on shaking on pause if shaking stop . i want a method for time to stop music

Comment: I have edited the answer to provide the solution you wanted, @hadi